# Trim, from a list of email addresses, all addresses matching a "forbidden domain" list

Tags: regex, bash

I have a list of email addresses (in a text file, one address per line):

```
u1@d1.com
u2@d1.com
u3@d1.com
u1@d2.com
u1@d3.com
u1@d4.com
u2@d4.com
```

I also have a list of domains (in a text file, one domain per line):

```
d1.com
d2.com
```

I am trying to write two bash scripts:

- One that will return a list that excludes any email address that matches ANY ONE of the domains in the second list (I will consider those ones the "good" ones)
- One that will return a list with ONLY the email addresses that match ANY ONE of the domains in the second list (I will delete users from my site who belong to those addresses)

What's the best, easiest way to get this done? I am rusty with bash, and am finding it tricky. The regular expression is basic.

Please note that I am not after complete solutions, but "key commands" to make this happen.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, with no comment. Nice.

Comment: You have not posted any code. What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: If a question shows the content of several files, it is practical give a name to each file. In this way, the answers can follow your naming proposal.

Comment: @tripleee: I do not see which kind of "code proposal" can be provided for question that ask about which command to use. Shells are not programming languages.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui You are absolutely right, I was silly

Comment: @tripleee It was my fault, I should have explained that I wasn't after *full* code, but after **key commands** to make it happen. Which is exactly what happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep command, like:

```
grep -f allowed_domains emails
```

to get the allowed emails, where "allowed_domains" is the second file you show in the question, "emails" is the first one. . Add "-v" for the not allowed emails.

If you want something stronger, add a "@" at start of each allowed_domain line. By example, as:

```
cat allowed_domains | xargs -L1 printf "@%s\n" | grep -f - emails
```

Comment: `grep -f` is the GEM I was after! I knew it must be possible somehow!

Comment: Or just `sed 's/^/@/' allowed_domains | fgrep -w -f - emails`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F@ 'NR==FNR{dom[$0]; next} {print > (($2 in dom)? "bad.txt":"good.txt")}' file2 file1

cat good.txt
u1@d3.com
u1@d4.com
u2@d4.com

cat bad.txt
u1@d1.com
u2@d1.com
u3@d1.com
u1@d2.com
```